# Extending View and add xml attributes from Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm developing an Android Button which will support both, Image and Text. This can be achieved with a Button and a compound drawable, but this have scaling issues.

I want the widget can be declared in xml having something like this

```
<ImageTextButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:text="@string/my_text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

The problem here is: I already draw the button and it scales right. I mean I know how to get `android:src` and it seems to work fine. But when I try to get the textSize something goes wrong.

I read the attributes like this:

```
int attrsArray[] = { android.R.attr.src, android.R.attr.textSize };
TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);

for (int i = 0; i < ta.getIndexCount(); i++) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
    int srcId = ta.getResourceId(i, 0);
    srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), srcId);
    break;
    case 1:
        float textSize = ta.getDimension(i, 0);
    if (textSize > 0) {
        Log.i("IMAGEBUTTON", "SETTING CUSTOM SIZE");
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    }
    break;
    }
}
```

But `ta.getIndexCount()` it's only returning 1, so the switch never enters `case 1`

What am I doing wrong? Is it necessary to declare my custom view as styleable? If that's the case, can I do it without creating a new namespace?

**EDIT**

I solved my issue making a call to `super.getTextSize()`. This works assuming I inherit from `TextView`. For now I'm good, but I wanna know why my code didn't work. What to do if I don't inherit from `TextView` and want to add more android attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do but in the code that is here you always start the for loop in zero so always will enter to "case 0", never will enter to case 1

Comment: It will, if `ta.getIndexCount()` results to be greater than 1. Which it's supposed to be cuz I'm obtaining 2 attributes from the AttributeSet